# Converting Multiple Numerical Data types in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, primitive-types

I'm having a bit of an issue with this program I have been working on for my class. It's a future values calculator, that takes a single data type, decimal data type and a integer data type does the formula and then spits back out the Future value. What I'm having difficulty with is converting the string over. We haven't covered how to do it in class and the book that the instructor had us buy isn't very good at all. I will post my code so far and hopefully you can help me out.

```
Public Class Form1

    'Define the Module level variables
    Dim FutureValueInteger As Integer

    Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
        'Define the local variables
        Dim InitialIvestmentDecimal As Decimal
        Dim RateSingle As Single
        Dim YearsInteger As Integer

        Try 'Try the Initial investment
            InitialIvestmentDecimal = Decimal.Parse(InitialInvestmentTextBox.Text)

            Try 'Try the Rate
                RateSingle = Single.Parse(RateTextBox.Text)

                Try 'Try the years
                    YearsInteger = Integer.Parse(YearsTextBox.Text)

                    Try 'Try the math
                        FutureValueInteger = InitialIvestmentDecimal * (1 * RateSingle) ^ YearsInteger

                        FutureValueLabel.Text = FutureValueInteger.ToString("C")


                    Catch ex As Exception 'Catch the math

                    End Try
                Catch ex As Exception 'Catch the years

                End Try
            Catch ex As Exception 'Catch the Rate

            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception 'Catch the Initial investment

        End Try



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. FYI, you should use "VB.NET" instead of "VB". You should also leave out any "Hello" or "Thanks".

Comment: On a separate topic, you should stop using Try/Catch all over the place. You're ignoring every exception that gets thrown. You'll never find out what's wrong with your code that way.

Comment: What's the problem?  The code ran for me.  Are you getting an exception, or just asking how else to do it?

Comment: I'm using the try/catch in that manner because that is the way the teacher/book is telling us to do it and unfortunately as I have never used VB till this class it also has to be included other wise we won't receive full credit for the project. Yes the program runs but when I enter in the sample data I'm not getting back the correct amount. the sample data is Initial Investment: 2000 Rate: .15 Years" 5 and that is supposed to come out to 4022.71 in the future values box

Comment: but it's returning to me a $0 answer. All our teacher told us was that we need to convert the data types so it's all one data type. like i said before i'm not really sure if thats correct or not and he isn't exactly there greatest teacher but it's all i have to go by.

Comment: @user: if you need to do this for class, then you should change schools. Once you're out of school, stop doing this, as it's one of the worst programming practices ever.

Comment: yes i'm currently at the local community college but will be transferring to OIT Oregon Institute of Technology to get my CIS degree, this is just one mandatory class that I'm required to take, and I thought it my be a better idea taking it in a smaller class setting but I didn't realize how bad the teacher/book would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Visual Studio.  Are you familiar with the **Immediate Window**.
http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2007/12/visual-studio-immediate-window.html

Basically, it will help you debug problems like this.

```
? InitialIvestmentDecimal * (1 * RateSingle) ^ YearsInteger
```

Returns a value of 0.15187503017485382

When you try to set the 'FutureValueInteger' = to 0.15... you end up with 0.  An Integer can't handle the information after the decimal point.

It looks like your formula is wrong.

http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/future-value.php

You probably want something like this instead...

```
FutureValueInteger = InitialIvestmentDecimal * (1 + RateSingle) ^ YearsInteger
```

FutureValueInteger is still an integer - so your result is going to be 4023 instead of 4022.71.  You'll probably be better off making FuturevalueInteger a Decimal and rounding.

Take a look at Math.Round